# Can I use JQuery functions on a variable and not have JQuery reference the DOM over and over again?

Tags: jquery

```
var x = $("element");
$(x).width(95);
```

Very, very new to JQuery. I want to get an item from the DOM and use jQuery functions on that item. I want to make sure I am not getting the item from the DOM over and over again. Would this do that or am I getting the item from the DOM the second time?

If I am can avoid that and use jQuery functions? How would I do that?

Do I need to care? I feel that I really should.

Comment: Just `x.width(95);`

Comment: Amit is right. But, on the other hand, isn't jquery clever enough to very quickly realize that `x` *is* a jquery object already that does not need to be found again?

Comment: @cars10 It is, and there is a separate overload for that: [*When a jQuery object is passed to the `$()` function, a clone of the object is created. This new jQuery object references the same DOM elements as the initial one*](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-object).

Answer (score 3):

> I want to make sure I am not getting the item from the DOM over and over again. Would this do that or am I getting the item from the DOM the second time?

No.

`$()` returns a jQuery object that contains a collection of elements. They have already been found in DOM.

You do not need to pass it to `$` either, it is already "`$`":

```
var x = $("element");
x.width(95);
```

If you do pass a `$`  object to `$`, that [creates a copy of the collection](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-object) - it does not search the items again, but it clones the list.

> Do I need to care? I feel that I really should.

Yes, you do and you should. Executing a selector against DOM can be expensive. You don't want to be executing it every time.

Answer (score 0):

You are indeed right in thinking about performance while trying to access the same DOM element multiple times.

`var x = $("element");` This fetches the element from the DOM and stores it in x. 
So you can directly do `x.width(95);`, without the need to use a `$(x) again`.
Since most functions in jQuery return a reference to `this`, functions can be chained. So you could call functions further, like `x.function1().function2()` and so on.